# "Серіал" - нормативне слово?

Tags: вживання-слів, іменники

Взято з Вікіпедії

> [Серіа́л](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BB) — поширене та популярне явище сучасного мистецтва, яке
> використовується (трапляється) переважно в літературі, кіно,
> телебаченні та анімації; спосіб організації та побудови художніх
> творів, котрий полягає в тому, що твір складається з багатьох окремих
> частин, зазвичай відносно невеликого розміру.

Слово "серіал" широко вживаєть повсякдено в розмові та можна зустріті на письмі. Чи є дане слово нормативним? Адже в словниках я його не знайшла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У [«Словниках України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) є слово *серіал*, зокрема там зазначені його форми для різних відмінків.

У «Українсько-англійському словнику ділової людини» (Є. І. Гороть, О. В. Василенко, Н. В. Єфремова та ін.; 2014) є словосполучення *телевізійний серіал*:

> **телевізійн||ий** *прикм.* television (*attr.*); **~ий глядач** television viewer
>
> - …
> - **~ий [серіал](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BB&dicts=14&highlight=on&filter_lines=on)** television series
> - …

Також це слово згадується в безлічі цитат зі «Словника української мови» в 20 томах:

> *[Антуражний](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=194672&page=63) серіал, показаний на телебаченні, заворожував жіночим одягом марокканок і неймовірно красивою музикою* (з газ.)
>
> *Поява українськомовних трилерів, [бойовиків](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=5032&page=188) та серіалів у сучасній індустрії кіно — неминуча* (з газ.).
>
> *Негативну роль відіграє [глорифікація](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=188824&page=642) кримінального світу в чисельних романах, фільмах, серіалах* (із журн.).
>
> *Ці канали мають без проблем стільки реклами, скільки хочуть, і тоді, коли побажають, не опускаючись для цього до показу [другосортних](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=157116&page=835) касових серіалів* (з газ.).
>
> *Йшов, з'ясувалося, якийсь шпетно [дубльований](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?page=839&wordid=25237) бразильський серіал* (О. Забужко); *Дубльовані українською мовою фільми й серіали зробили значно більше для українізації молоді, ніж дидактичні повчання й патріотичні заклики* (із журн.).
>
> *У Гонконзі знімають комедійні серіали, що поширюються по всьому [китайськомовному](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?page=1316&wordid=210410) світу* (з наук.-попул. літ.).
>
> *[Кінокритики](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=205825&page=1322) віднесли серіал «Величне століття. Роксолана» до найкрасивіших історичних серіалів* (з газ.).